# Maven SNAPSHOT does not generate snapshot version

Tags: maven

I am using `pom.xml` with following content. I am expecting it to generate a war file with unique id, but it keeps on generating war file with name `myproject-0.1.0.Build-SNAPSHOT.war`.

I would like my war file to be created with unique id. Something like https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/. I compared my pom file with the pom file in the folder, but could not locate much differece.

Command used:

```
mvn package
```

pom.xml file: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWmpZb

Comment: Are you using a repository manager like nexus or artifactory?

Comment: Yes. Our company uses artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

If you need versioned snapshots then you can get them from your managed repository following a `mvn deploy`.

It stores SNAPSHOTS with a timestamped version, such as

```
  myproject-0.1.0.Build-20170403.013619-3.war
```

These can normally retrieved via HTTP.

Alternatively, if you're using git and Maven 3.2.1 or newer you can do something like:

Configure your default profile in settings.xml with a property named `sha1`:

```
<properties>
   ...
   <sha1>SNAPSHOT</sha1>
   ...
</properties>
```

Then you can execute maven like:

```
mvn clean install -Dsha1=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
```

and get a locally built artifact that is versioned like:

```
myproject-0.1.0.Build-9b5a664.war
```

This is a version coupled with your last `git commit`.

Details of this and similar mechanisms are in the [Maven 3.2.1 Release Notes](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html).

Comment: Using deploy goal helped a bit. Now I see following line in Maven logs. However, I cannot download it from artifactory with the same URL. I need to use .war file name without the unique id. Is this expected?  `http://artifactory.mycompany.com/myproject-snapshots/com/myproject/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/MyProject-0.1.0-20170503.232816-1.war`.

Comment: Usually you can browse the "raw" repository and get a direct versioned and timestamped artefact URL which you can feed to a deployment script.

Comment: Artifactory has something called as "Native Browser" - which basically shows directory listing on browser. Even there, I can see `MyProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` and not `MyProject-0.1.0-20‌​170503.232816-1.war`.